# Static noise through speakers when plugged into PC

Tags: usb, audio, motherboard, speakers, ground

I recently obtained a pair of really nice powered speakers for my computer setup- Dynaudio LYD 5s. My issue is as follows: when plugged into my PC, and powered on, the speakers make a very loud, almost radio sounding static noise. The setup I am using to connect the speakers is via a XLR Y cable, through a DAC, finally plugging into one of the USB ports on my motherboard. I have tested this setup with my Macbook, it works perfectly there, with no static noise- the issue is definitely on the side of my PC, not any of my audio equipment.

Here's what I have tried so far to fix:

- Reinstalling/Updating sound drivers
- Configuring sound settings every which way
- Following almost every 'remove static from speakers PC' guide I could find on the internet
- Verifying that the issue is probably not caused by a ground loop- all of the items in my setup are plugged into the same power bar, and besides, the speakers work perfectly through the Macbook.
- Plugging the XLR cable directly into the audio output on the motherboard, without using the DAC, the static noise persists.
- Plugging the DAC into the USB port on my PC case, didn't make any difference from the motherboard's USB ports, probably because that port is routed directly to the motherboard.

At this point I'm fairly sure it's my motherboard causing the issue, as all ports on the motherboard or connected to the motherboard are generating the noise. I have no issues when using my headset, which is also connected to my motherboard via a different USB audio. Does anyone have any ideas as to what the problem could be?

Here are my system specs:

- CPU: i7 8700k
- Cooler: NZXT Kraken x52
- Mobo: ROG Strix B360-H
- RAM: 32gb 3200MHz
- GPU: GTX 1080 FE
- PSU: EVGA 750 GQ 80+ Gold Certified

Comment: What USB DAC are you using ?

Comment: Audioquest Dragonfly Red